# Sympy error: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Mul which has no callable log method

Tags: sympy

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as si
import sympy as sy

def price(S, K, T, r, vol, call=True):
    d1 = (np.log(S / K) + (r + 0.5 * vol ** 2) * T) / (vol * np.sqrt(T))
    d2 = (np.log(S / K) + (r - 0.5 * vol ** 2) * T) / (vol * np.sqrt(T))
    if call:
        price = (S * si.norm.cdf(d1, 0.0, 1.0) - K * np.exp(-r * T) * si.norm.cdf(d2, 0.0, 1.0))
    else:
        price = (K * np.exp(-r * T) * si.norm.cdf(-d2, 0.0, 1.0) - S * si.norm.cdf(-d1, 0.0, 1.0))
    return price

p,S,K,T,r, vol, call = sy.symbols('p S K T r vol call')
exp = p - price(S, K, T, r, vol, call)
```

When i run this i get the following error: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Mul which has no callable log method

When i checked online there was mention of not scoping my log function but I have done this so this is not the problem. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Don't mix `sympy` and `scipy/numpy` - at least not without good knowledge of both.

Comment: You are passing `sympy` objects to `numpy` functions like `log` and `sqrt`.  That does not work.  `numpy/scipy` code is designed to work with numbers and `numpy` arrays, not objects imported from a different package.

Comment: Thanks I have now rewritten the function so it relies only on sympy so I no longer get the error message. I now have a new more interesting problem so I shall post a new question for this. Again thanks:

Comment: import sympy as sy
import sympy.stats as systats
def euro_vanilla_price(S, K, T, r, vol, call=True):
    
    N = systats.Normal("n",0.0, 1.0)
    
    d1 = (sy.ln(S / K) + (r + 0.5 * vol ** 2) * T) / (vol * sy.sqrt(T))
    d2 = (sy.ln(S / K) + (r - 0.5 * vol ** 2) * T) / (vol * sy.sqrt(T))
    norm_d1 = systats.cdf(N)(d1)
    norm_d2 = systats.cdf(N)(d2)
    
    if call:
        price = (S * norm_d1 - K * sy.exp(-r * T) * norm_d2)
    else: price = (K * sy.exp(-r * T) *( 1-norm_d2) - S * (1-norm_d1))
    
    return price